# Limit number of CFHTTP requests sent every x seconds

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp

I'm making an application that will continually send CFHTTP requests to a server to search for items, as well as sending further CFHTTP requests to perform actions on any returned results.

The issue I'm having is that the server has a maximum threshold of 3 requests per second and even when I try to implement a sleep call every 4 milliseconds it doesn't work properly as, although it delays, the CFHTTP requests can queue up if it takes them a couple of seconds to return so that it then tries to send multiple in the same second triggering the threshold to be exceeded.

Is there a way I can ensure that there are never more than 3 active CFHTTP requests?

Comment: I would start by ensuring that making that many requests that quickly is really necessary.  If it's not, you could simply do a cfhttp followed by a 1 second sleep inside a loop.

Comment: The more requests I can make as quickly as possible the more effective the application would be. The issue I've had with doing a sleep is that cfhttp calls can still queue up and then multiple request at the same time resulting in the threshold being exceeded.

Comment: Are you running _standard_ or _enterprise_ edition of ColdFusion?

Comment: Enterprise at work but standard at home

Comment: Are you seeing the same limit on both versions? When the threshold is reached are the subsequent requests failing or queuing up?

Comment: The subsequent requests are being sent but they are returning an error because as soon as I exceed the threshold my session gets expired.

Comment: I must be missing something. It does not make sense to me that your session is getting expired because you have reached a thread limit on your cfhttp calls. Are you sure that you are chasing the correct problem here? Instead of limiting your requests should you be looking at why your session is expiring or why the subsequent requests are bombing out? Not that you want to saturate cfhttp requests to the server but if they queue up (as designed) it should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to need to implement some sort of logging widget as part of your process. The log will keep track of request frequency. If the threshold is not met, then you would just skip over that iteration of your CFHTTP call. I don't mean a file log or a database log, but something implemented in the application or even request scope depending on your implementation. There is no way to throttle CFHTTP itself. It is basically a very simplistic wrapper around a Java HTTP library which then goes straight to the underlying operating system.

Comment: Would having an application variable that stores the GetTickCount of the previous three requests and checking that if the time from the first item is greater than 1 second then do the next CFHTTP call be a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you're limiting *concurrent* requests, then first part of this answer applies. If you're looking to limit the number of requests per second, then the bit at the end applies. The question kind of asks both things.

If I understand correctly, you've got a number of threads (either as requests CF is processing or threads CF has created itself) which all need to make calls to the same rate-limited domain. What you need is a central way of co-ordinating access, combined with a nice way of controlling program execution.

I don't know of any native limits that CF might support (I'd be happy to be proven wrong) so you're likely to have to implement your own. The cheap'n'nasty way to do this is to increment  and decrement a `allowed_conenctions` variable in a long-lived scope such as appliation. The downsides are that you have to implement checking all over the place and that if there are no spare connections, you'll have to wait somehow.

Really what you have is a [resource poo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_%28computer_science%29)l (of allowed HTTP connections) and I'm guessing that you want your code to wait until a connection is free. CF does this kind of thing already for database connections.

In your case, there isn't really a need to keep anything in a pool (as HTTP connections aren't long-lived), other than a permit to use the resource. Java provides a class which ought to provide what you're after, the [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

I've not tried it but in theory, something like the snippet below ought to work:

```
//Application.cfc:onApplicationStart()
application.http_pool = CreateObject("java","java.util.concurrent.Semaphore").init(3)

//Meanwhile, elsewhere in your code
application.http_pool.acquire()
//Make my HTTP call
application.http_pool.release()
```

You could even wrap the HTTP object to provide this functionality without having to use the acquire/release each time, which would make it more reliable.

EDIT
It you're looking to limit rates, look at guava's [RateLimiter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) which has the same general interface as Semaphore above, but implements rate limiting for you. You'd need to add guava to ColdFusion's classpath, or use JavaLoader or use CF10 which has classloading facilities built-in.

Comment: I'm not sure if when each request has been sent I set an incremental Application.activeRequests variable until it is 3, wrap IF statements round all requests to check that the current value is less than 3, and have another IF statement after every request which will decrease 1 from the activeRequests variable if a response has been received would be a good approach?

Comment: I think the major factor in this is what you want to happen when the active requests or rate limit kick in. If you're happy to have your code give up and throw an error, then the application.activeRequests approach will work. If you want to wait, then you have two choices: Write a while loop to sleep/check or use a blocking call. The loop approach is messy, but could be achieved in pure CF code. If you write a HTTP object wrapper around ColdFusion's HTTP object, you could hide the loop, but you're responsible for handling the corner cases yourself. If you use RateLimiter it is handled for you

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but I've never incorporated a java class in to any of my CF projects. Is it something that's quite easy to do?

Comment: Yes, it should be straightforward. If you're looking to block concurrent connections, then the snippets above should work as-is.

Comment: Using an external JAR like guava is pretty simple using JavaLoader or CF10's loader. Download the JAR then follow the instructions from JavaLoader. It's particularly easy in the case of Guava as it has no other dependencies (other than Java 1.6)